# Add the " symbol in a QStringList

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a `QStringList` containing all punctuation signs.

How can I add the element `"` into it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\` to escape the character `"`. The code may look like this:

```
QStringList foo;
foo << "\"";
```

An other option would be to construct a `QString` from a char declared between simple quotes `'`:

```
foo << QString('"');
```

Since the constructor isn't declared as `explicit` in [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-2), this should also work with implicit conversion:

```
foo << '"';
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks !